# Pegar input file com várias classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho um input file com duas classes.

```
<input type="file" class="upload upload-logo" />
<input type="file" class="upload upload-rules" />
<input type="file" class="upload upload-image" />
```

Quero criar um código genérico para todos os inputs.
Este funciona, mas tenho de criar 1 bloco por cada input:

```
$("input[class=upload-logo]").change(function() {
            ...
        });
```

Já testei assim, mas não funciona:

```
$("input[class=upload]").change(function() {
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira como está a selecionar não é a mais convencionada, se quer selecionar elementos segundo uma classe pode simplesmente:

```js
$('.upload').on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).prop('class')); // só a titulo de exemplo, para ver o input em que selecionou o ficheiro
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="upload upload-logo" />
<input type="file" class="upload upload-rules" />
<input type="file" class="upload upload-image" />
```

Para que fique claro, o seu não estava a dar porque não estava a usar o seletor corretamente:

```js
$('input[class^="upload"]').on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).prop('class')); // só a titulo de exemplo, para ver o input em que selecionou o ficheiro
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="upload upload-logo" />
<input type="file" class="upload upload-rules" />
<input type="file" class="upload upload-image" />
```

[REFERÊNCIA](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)